# Graph: Expected number of copy of $H$.

Tags: graph-theory

Denote by $H$ the graph obtained from $K_4$ by deleting one edges. Calculated the expected number of induced copy of $H$ in $G(n,p)$. Here $G(n,p)$ is a random model with edges probability equal to $p$.

**My Answer**

We delete an edges from $K_4$ with probability $1-p$. There is $6$ copy of $H$ (because $K_4$ has $6$ edges). Therefore the expectation number is $6(1-p)$.

Is it correct ?

Comment: As a sanity check, there should be a dependence on $n$ in your expression: the bigger $n$ is, the bigger the random graph is on expectation, and the more likely you'll find any fixed pattern as an induced subgraph. While if $n\leq 3$, the answer can only be $0$.

Comment: Multiply your number by $p^5$ and you get the probability that a set of 4 vertices induces a diamond ($K_4$ minus edge). Multiply by $n \choose 4$ for the expectation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix any tuple $T$ of $4$ vertices: in a $n$-node graph, there are $\binom{n}{4}$ such distincts tuples. To become a copy of $H$, $T$ must have exactly $5$ edges out of $6$, which since the edges are decided independently happens with probability $$ \binom{6}{1} p^5(1-p)^1 = 6p^5(1-p) $$
(the $\binom{6}{1}$ coming from the $6$ ossible configurations: which edge is to be removed). Now, by linearity of expectation (which holds, conveniently, regardless of independence between the choices of different tuples $T$), the number of copies of $H$ in the ${G}(n,p)$ graph will satisfy
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E} X &= \sum_{T} \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1_{T\equiv H}}] = \sum_{T} 6p^5(1-p) = \binom{n}{4} \cdot 6p^5(1-p) \\
&= \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{4} p^5 (1-p).
\end{align}$$

Now, to check whether this is reasonable ("sanity check"):

- this is $0$ for $p=1$ (where you can only get $K_n$) and $p=0$ (where you get no edges at all);
- this is $0$ for $n \leq 3$;
- this goes to infinity when $n$ grows (for fixed $p\in(0,1)$): the bigger the graph, the more likely to find any fixed pattern in it.

Comment: Now, if someone has an intuition (or a handwavy explanation) to *why* $p$ has to scale roughly as $1/n^{4/5}$ in order to get on expectation a constant number of copies, I'm interested.